# How can I separate/duplicate Smart Object Layers displayed twice to be able to edit individually in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I have a mock-up of two boxes that I'm editing but unfortunately there is only one smart layer per box - meaning the design of both boxes ends up being the same. As I want to have two different boxes, I need to be able to edit the smart object layers of each box individually. Does someone know how I could do this?

Here a screenshot of the mock up, as you see on the right there are only 3 smart layers (left, front, top) which end up editing the design of the boxes to be exactly the same.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Right-click/Control-click the Smart Object in the **Layers Panel** 
and choose **`New Smart Object Via Copy`** from the **Contextual Pop Up Menu**.

[image]

This *duplicates* the smart object but *breaks* the link to the other smart object(s) - creating an unconnected smart object with the same contents.

Afterwards, edits to the new smart object will *not* be updated in the other smart object(s).

Answer (score 0):

- Click the Smart Layer with the right mouse button and choose Duplicate Layer → Destination → New document
- In the new document change the Smart Layer Name and click it with the right mouse button and choose Duplicate Layer → Destination → the original document